# Coroutne не перехватывают кастомные исключения

Tags: android, kotlin, coroutine

Решил перевести проект с rxjava на coroutne,начал с retrofit

//кофиг ретрофита

```
       mAuthRetrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl(BASE_URL_AUTH)
        .client(authClient())
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .addCallAdapterFactory(CoroutineCallAdapterFactory())
        .build()

        fun authClient() =OkHttpClient.Builder().addInterceptor { chain ->
            val response = chain.proceed(chain.request())
            when (response.code()) {
               400 -> throw ErrorLogin()
               ... 
            }
        response
       }.build()
```

//метод из интерфейса для retrofit

```
 @Headers("Content-Type: application/json")
 @POST("auth/login")
 suspend fun login(@Body body: UserBody): UserApiPojo
```

//сам вызов в презентере

```
    val errorHandler = CoroutineExceptionHandler { context, exception ->
      Timber.e(exception)
 }

fun clickLogin() {
    if (loginAndPassIsNotEmpty()) {
        viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO + errorHandler) {
            val result = runCatching { repository.auth.login(login, password) }
            result.onSuccess { user ->
                repository.auth.saveUser(user)
                withContext(Dispatchers.Main + errorHandler) {
                    router.loginComplete()
                }
            }.onFailure { error ->
                viewState?.let { view ->
                    when (error) {
                        is ErrorLogin -> view.showErrorLogin()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Если запрос успешный то все работает хорошо, но если я ввожу неверные данные, то у меня OkHttpClient обрабатывает данные и возращает ошибку ErrorLogin(). На rx  далее без проблем перехватывал тот или Exception и далее уже в презентере выполнял те или ные действия. Почему здесь приложение крашится и ошибка не поподает ни в errorHandler  ни в result.onFailure

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: OkHttp Dispatcher
Process: ru.exomple.app, PID: 11546
java.lang.Error: ru.exomple.app.api.error.ErrorLogin: Login or password wrong
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1173)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919)
 Caused by: ru.exomple.app.api.error.ErrorLogin: Login or password wrong
    at ru.exomple.app.api.AppService$authSetupClient$1.intercept(AppService.kt:48)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
    at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:254)
    at okhttp3.RealCall$AsyncCall.execute(RealCall.java:200)
    at okhttp3.internal.NamedRunnable.run(NamedRunnable.java:32)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
```

Я конечно могу убрать  throw ErrorLogin() из OkHttpClient. Но мне хотелось понимать как все это работает и почему эти ошибки не ловятся.

Comment: Какая версия Котлин?

Comment: ErrorLogin, он кто?

Comment: @IR42 kotlin_version = "1.3.72"

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja это свой exception class ErrorLogin : Exception("Login or password wrong").

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы ваши исключения ловились `Retrofit`-ом и передавались вызываемому коду, они должны быть унаследованы от `IOException`. Все другие считаются фатальными и пропускаются выше.

Вот тут была дискуссия почему так: https://github.com/square/okhttp/pull/5457
Вот тут ответ enSO: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58711127/5479247